# Firebase: Check if user is logged before rendering page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I check if user is logged or not and then render my react app?
I tried using await but it was not working.
Because there is some logic in my app, and it looks like some of firebase request in it are resolving earlier than auth check.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged ( user => {
 if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
  console.log("logged as", user.email);
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(user.mail));

} else {
  console.log("User logged out");
  // User is signed out.   
store.dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));


 }
})


ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
 </Provider>,

 document.getElementById("root")
);
```